# How to concate two styled div using props in styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-redux, styled-components

I want to concate two div in a styled component using prop value

```js
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

interface Props {
  isValue: boolean;
}

export const sample = css`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 0 0 16px;
`;

export const sample1 = styled.div<Props>`
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  ${(props) => (props.isValue ? sample : '')};
`;
```

I have tried the above code , it is not working

Requirement: If isValue is true sample should get added to sample1 as shown below

so sample1 should contain

```css
padding-bottom: 12px;
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: 12px 0 0 16px;
```

If isValue is false it should show only sample1 values

Comment: What is the text, what you trying to achieve? You don't tell us about the actual problem you facing

Comment: Sometext is boolean value (true or false) if sometext is true then append sample1 with sample

Comment: @Dennis Vash  I have changed my question

Comment: This code will work, no problem with it. Please create a reproducible example in codesandbox if you want further help. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ${(props) => (props.isValue ? sample : '')};  this value is coming as an array

Comment: Show code instead, read the link.